# how to override php function

Tags: php, function, overriding

I have a page that call this php page of function

**myfunction.php**

```
function create($array) { /* create new one in db */ }

function modify($array) { /* modify a row in database */ }

function delete($array) { /* delete a row from database */ }

... (other function)
```

and have some page that needs different create content function...

Then I create this file, but I got error

**myfunction2.php**

```
include myfunction.php

function create($array) { /* create new one in db */ }
```

What's the best way to create a file of function and override when is needed ?

Comment: You can assign an anonymous function to a variable, then if it exists, unset it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8691911/715105

Comment: Take a look at this http://php.net/manual/en/function.runkit-function-redefine.php

Comment: better use oop and class Inheritance